# unable to pass method reference in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Below code works fine for passing reference of method while creating component dynamically or you can [click me](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) for help

```
cmp.getReference("c.handlePress")
```

how to pass reference of method if i'm not creating my component dynamically.

```
<c:myComp method={"c.hadelpress"} />
```

i want something like above

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to define `method` attribute of type `Aura.Action` in your child component and pass the `{!c.methodName}` to your child component from the parent/container component.

**myComp.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="method" type="Aura.Action" />
    <button onclick="{!v.method}" type="button"> click me </button>
</aura:component>
```

**main.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <c:myComp method="{!c.handlepress}" />
</aura:component>
```

**maincontroller.js:**

```
({
    "handlepress" : function(cmp,event,helper) {
        console.log('button click');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Apart from praveen's solution you can try this one if you have a registered event. If you want to call passed function from controller and helper then use following code:

Handler function can be assigned to registered event in the component.

Suppose in c:someComponent I have

```
<aura:registerEvent name="onSomeThing" type="c:someEvent"/>
```

then, I can write as follows-

```
<c:someComponent onSomeThing="{!c.handleSomeThing}" />
```

Comment: Saurabh, there's no need to call the `$A.enqueueAction()` method for this case. The parent controller method will be correctly binded to the child component's onclick event when passed as attribute. I have updated your answer answer.

Comment: Ok. @Praveen $A.enqueueAction() is needed only if function is to be called from controller or helper otherwise what you said is right. Please see following question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146575/calling-aura-action-attribute-from-lightning-controller-helper