# Communicate to parent without event

Tags: lightning-aura-components

> We have Two Components. One is ComponentA and another one is
>   ComponentB. ComponentB is child of ComponentA. We need to communicate
>   ComponentB to ComponentA. I know it can be done using Component event.
>   Instead of creating a event, I saw an approach here. Is it advisable
>   to use it?

I refer this

[Calling Aura.Action attribute from Lightning Controller/Helper](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146575/calling-aura-action-attribute-from-lightning-controller-helper)

[Using the Action Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_aura_action.htm?search_text=$A.enqueueAction)

**ComponentA.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:ComponentB method="{!c.press}"/>
</aura:application>
```

**ComponentAController.js**

```
({
    press : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        console.log("Method Called from Child");
    }
})
```

**ComponentB.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="method" type="Aura.action" access="public"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="press" onclick="{!c.press}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**ComponentBController.js**

```
({
    press : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        console.log("generate componentA's method");
        $A.enqueueAction(cmp.get("v.method"));
    }
})
```

Comment: you can use it as this will not throw any error but you can't pass any value using that.

Comment: Why not use `aura:method`: [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm)

Comment: @Itai Shmida, We can't use aura:method because we are invoking parent method from child