# Testing Lightning component that fires event based upon a child component's `onchange` action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-testing-service, jasmine

I'm trying to write Jasmine/LTS tests for a component that embeds a `<lightning:combobox>`. The method I'm attempting to test fires a component event within a controller method that is bound to the combo box's `onchange` attribute, and then resets the combo box's value to a default. It works in actual use.

I've reviewed all of the example tests in the [Lightning Testing Service](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/blob/master/lightning-component-tests/test/default/staticresources/jasmineExampleTests.resource) repository, and none of them quite fit this pattern.

The best I've been able to come up with (since doing `combobox.set('v.value', SOME_VALUE)` from test code does not fire the controller change handler) is to obtain the `Aura.Action` value for the controller handler via `combobox.get('v.onchange');` and directly invoke it with a synthetic `event` parameter. I can then use Jasmine spies to verify that my component fires its own event correctly.

This code does invoke the right controller method, and the spies work correctly:

```
combobox.get('v.onchange')();
```

but this doesn't populate any parameters in the `event`, like the real combo box does and which my controller relies on. Hence the test case fails.

I've seen [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146575/calling-aura-action-attribute-from-lightning-controller-helper/146598) from a year or so ago that covers the same area but without a clear resolution (see the comments on the accepted answer). I'm also aware that there are more-recommended design options that might change the test structure, but I would like to learn how this works since it is supported with `<lightning:combobox>` and other components.

So here's the question, ultimately:

- How do we populate the `event` parameter when directly invoking an `Aura.Action` in test context?
- *or*, is this the wrong approach to test this type of component-to-component linking?

Herewith some code snippets.

The component:

```
<aura:component controller="myController">
    <aura:attribute name="statusOptions" type="Object[]" access="PRIVATE" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="navigateEvent" type="c:navigateEvent" />

    <lightning:combobox aura:id="entitySelector" 
                        name="entitySelector" 
                        label="Select"
                        placeholder="Selection"
                        onchange="{! c.handleComboNavigate }"
                        options="{! v.statusOptions }" />
</aura:component>
```

And the controller:

```
handleComboNavigate : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = component.getEvent('navigateEvent');
    var entity = event.getParam('value');

    evt.setParam('entity', entity); // real code has some transformation on `entity` that's not relevant here.                    
    evt.fire();

    event.getSource().set('v.value', null);
}
```

Current stab at test case:

```
it('fires event upon navigate', function(done) {
    // Fire the combobox's update event.
    var res = { getState : function() { return 'SUCCESS'; }, 
                getReturnValue: function() { return [ { label: 'Test Train', value: '100'} ]; } };

    // Spy on both enqueueAction, to fake the server controller response...
    // (combo box is populated via Apex controller)
    spyOn($A, 'enqueueAction').and.callFake(function(action) {
        var cb = action.getCallback("SUCCESS")
        cb.fn.apply(cb.s, [res]);
    });

    $T.createComponent('c:entitySelectionComponent', {}, true)
    .then(function(component) {
        // and getEvent, so we can spy on the event firing.
        var eventSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('eventSpy', ['setParam', 'fire']);
        var getEvent = spyOn(component, 'getEvent').and.returnValue(eventSpy);
        var selectList = component.find('entitySelector');

        selectList.set('v.value', '100');            
        selectList.get('v.onchange')({ 'value' : '100' });

        expect(getEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(eventSpy.fire).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(eventSpy.setParam).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ selectedEntity: '100' });

        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI, a comment pointing to this was added to one of my questions - an alternative to LTS where "Most of Aura Lightning calls are emulated so you have no dependency with Salesforce at all" - [Testing Lightning Components in production with mocha-aura](https://medium.com/all-technology-feeds/testing-lightning-components-in-production-with-mocha-aura-e8ac039a89ac).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the "go another way" answer, which allows moving forward with testing but doesn't address the underlying technical questions above regarding how to test a specific type of component-to-component linkage.

Instead of providing a controller action in `<lightning:combobox>`'s `onchange` attribute, utilize a value binding to connect the combo box's value to a component attribute:

```
<aura:component controller="myController">
    <aura:attribute name="statusOptions" type="Object[]" access="PRIVATE" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedEntity" type="Object" access="PRIVATE" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{! v.selectedEntity }" action="{! c.handleComboNavigate }" />

    <aura:registerEvent name="navigateEvent" type="c:navigateEvent" />

    <lightning:combobox aura:id="entitySelector" 
                        name="entitySelector" 
                        value="{! v.selectedEntity }"
                        options="{! v.statusOptions }" />
</aura:component>
```

This makes the component/combobox link accessible in a test, because the component's attribute can be directly set and there's no requirement to populate the controller action's `event` parameter.

Jasmine spies in this instance both fake the response from the server and show that the correct event-firing calls are made within the component when its value is updated.

```
it('fires event upon navigate', function(done) {
    var res = { getState : function() { return 'SUCCESS'; }, 
                getReturnValue: function() { return [ { entity: '100'} ]; } };

    // Spy on both enqueueAction, to fake the server controller response...
    spyOn($A, 'enqueueAction').and.callFake(function(action) {
        var cb = action.getCallback("SUCCESS")
        cb.fn.apply(cb.s, [res]);
    });

    $T.createComponent('c:entitySelector', {}, true)
    .then(function(component) {
        // and getEvent, so we can spy on the event firing.
        var eventSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('eventSpy', ['setParam', 'fire']);
        var getEvent = spyOn(component, 'getEvent').and.returnValue(eventSpy);
        var selectList = component.find('entitySelector');

        selectList.set('v.value', '100');
        expect(getEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(eventSpy.fire).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(eventSpy.setParam).toHaveBeenCalledWith('entity', { entity: '100' });

        done();
    });
});
```