# Error setting onchange for a lightning:dualListbox but not other lightning:* components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningselect, lightning-duallistbox

I am getting the below error for the `lightning:dualListbox` but not for the `lightning:select` in the below component code. The component is being dynamically created. Other dynamically created `lightning:input` components also don't hit this error.

> {"status":"ERROR","message":"Assertion Failed!: \"onchange\" must
>   either be a public property of lightningDualListbox or a global HTML
>   attribute : false"}

```
<aura:attribute name="onchange" type="Aura.Action"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{! !v.multi }">
    <lightning:select
            name="{! v.name }"
            label="{! v.label }"
            value="{! v.value }"
            class="{! v.class }"
            onchange="{! v.onchange }"
            >
        <aura:iteration var="option" items="{!v.options}">
            <option value="{! option.value }">{! option.label }</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{! v.multi }">
    <div class="{! v.class }">
        <lightning:dualListbox
                name="{! v.name }"
                label="{! v.label }"
                value="{! v.value }"
                onchange="{! v.onchange }"
                options="{! v.options }"
                />
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

The `onchange` attribute value is:

```
var onchange = component.getReference('c.onFieldChange');
```

where `component` is the containing component for this and other dynamically created components.

Any suggestions for what a **global HTML attribute** is in this context? Or a way to get this code to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily after a few failures I think I have a workaround making use of the answer to [Calling Aura.Action attribute from Lightning Controller/Helper](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146575/calling-aura-action-attribute-from-lightning-controller-helper).

Only for the `lightning:dualListbox`, I've added a local controller method that then calls the external method and this seems to work:

```
<aura:attribute name="onchange" type="Aura.Action"/>

<lightning:dualListbox
    onchange="{! c.localOnchange }"
```

Controller:

```
localOnchange  : function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.enqueueAction(component.get("v.onchange"));
},
```